# Using pLaTeX with TexShop without setting it as default

Tags: texshop, ptex

I am trying to use pLaTeX to compile documents in Japanese in TexShop. As far as I know, the easiest way to do it is to change the TeXShop Preferences from [Regular] to [pTex (ptex2pdf)], as demonstrated by the screen capture below.

[image]

However, when I set it into [pTex (ptex2pdf)], I can no longer compile documents I created under normal LaTeX setting (written in English). Do any one with pTex experience have similar issues before?

My preliminary thought is that: if one can toggle between LaTeX and pTeX in the same way between LaTeX, XeLaTex, and cwTex, things would become much easier. And I am wondering how other people solve this issue. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

For the reference, here are the codes I want to compile:

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}[20pt]
\begin{document}
こんにちは！
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also added the code I want to compile so readers would know whether it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` and duplicate the file `XeLaTeX.engine`, renaming it `pLaTeX.engine`.

Then open the new file with TextEdit so it contains

```
#!/bin/sh
platex  -file-line-error -synctex=1 "$1"
```

Just copy here and replace the contents.

Now, at the beginning of the file you want to compile with `platex`, add

```
% !TEX TS-program = platex
```

That's all: relaunch TeXShop and when you click on the Typeset button you'll get this console output:

```
This is e-pTeX, Version 3.14159265-p3.6-141210-2.6 (utf8.euc) (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=platex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

You can still select the pLaTeX engine from the drop down menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, egreg! This helps me to get really close! Now the issue is that instead of compiling a PDF file, output is "written on test2.dvi (1 page, 272 bytes)" according to the log file. Does that also happen to you? I have added my codes to the original question post.

Comment: I am now able to compile without issue using this: ptex2pdf -u -l -ot -file-line-error -synctex=1 "$1"